# Django Url error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: "python"

Tags: python, django, tags

I am creating a little Django app with posts and tags. But I have some issues with my urls-models-views.  I can't see why in my application i am getting this error invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'python'. Here "python" is a tag. My files:
models.py:

```
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=55)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s" %(self.name)



class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    excerpt = models.TextField(blank=True, help_text="A small teaser of\
                your content")
    content = MarkupField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_published = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    objects = models.Manager()
    published_objects = PublishedManager()
    tags = TaggableManager()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ("date_created",)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"%s %s %s %s %s" %(self.title, self.date_created, self.is_published, self.category, self.tags)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/posts/%s/" % self.id
```

views.py:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.views.generic import ListView, RedirectView
from blog.models import Post
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse

def blogg(request):
    posts = Post.objects.get(title="generic views")
    ctx = {"posts":posts}
    return render_to_response("index.html",ctx, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def post_detail(request, post_id):

    post = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)


    return render_to_response("post_detail.html",
        {"post":post}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))


def tagdetail(request, tag):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(tags=tag)
    return render_to_response("tag_detail.html",
        {"posts":posts, "tags":tag}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', "blog.views.blogg"),
    url(r'^posts/(?P<post_title>\d+)/$',"blog.views.post_detail"),
    url(r'^posts/tag/(?P<tag>\w+)$',"blog.views.tagdetail"),
)
```

error:

```
ValueError at /posts/tag/python

invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'python'

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    
Django Version:     1.4.3
Exception Type:     ValueError
Exception Value:    

invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'python'

Exception Location:     /home/ada/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py in get_prep_value, line 537
Python Executable:  /home/ada/virtualenv/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.3
Python Path:    

['/home/ada/mainproject',
 '/home/ada/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/ada/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/ada/virtualenv/src/django-taggit',
 '/home/ada/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/ada/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg',
 '/home/ada/virtualenv/lib/python2.7',
 '/home/ada/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/home/ada/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/ada/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/home/ada/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/home/ada/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/ada/virtualenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL',
 '/home/ada/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/home/ada/virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL']

Can yo please tell me why I get this error:invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'python'
Thanks for help.
```

Comment: Please post the complete traceback.

Answer (score 1):

In django, `filter(tags=tag)` is a shortcut to `tags__pk=tag`, in your case, you have a tag name, so you should use `filter(tags__name=tag)`

Answer (score 0):

Update following line in your `tadgetails` view

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(tags=tag)
```

as

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(tags__name=tag)
```

Comment: Wow, solved. thank you very much, sometimes learning is difficult : )